# What is this mirrored rest?

Tags: notation, rests

I haven't seen this mirrored rest before (from Gymnopédie No. 1). What does it mean? How long of a rest is it?

[image: A measure of music in 3/4 with mirrored rest symbol follow by a minim]

Answer (score 3):

That's an old style crotchet (quarter note) rest before the minim (half note) chord. It's in the alto voice (as is the chord), which is why it's lower than the centre of the stave - you'll note the measure rest for the descant on the top line.

Answer (score 0):

It is a crotchet rest, sometimes written without the bottom bit - like a mirror image of the quaver rest. Easier to write by hand!